# java beginner recursion list

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to recursively print the elements of my list but I'm getting a stack overflow error and I'm not sure why because this line makes sure that it terminates

```
 if (index < elements.size()){
```

this is the instantiation of elements

```
public class RecursiveMethodsList<T extends Comparable<T>> { 

private ArrayList<T> elements= new ArrayList<>();
```

basically what I'm doing is going through a list and if i come across a value that is greater than or equal to my lowerval parameter and less than or equal to my upperval parameter I add it to a new list and return that new list once it's finished

this is my code for it

```
 private RecursiveMethodsList<E> returnBetween(int index, T lowerValue, T upperValue){ 

  RecursiveMethodsList<T> list = new RecursiveMethodsList<T>(); 

  if (index < elements.size()){ //line that prevents overflow 

     if (elements.get(index).compareTo(lowerValue) >= 0 &&
           (elements.get(index).compareTo(upperValue)) <= 0){

        list.add(elements.get(index)); }

     else retBetween(index++, lowerValue, upperValue); 

  }
  return list; 
}
```

I don't know why i'm receiving the error and I don't know how to structurally fix it.

Comment: `index++`, i´d check what you´re passing to the recursive call here, you want a `++index` as the postincrement will simply pass `index`. As a sidenode you also want to do `return retBetween(...)` here aswell as you´d be returning list once a single recursion would occur. On the the next other hand you´d probably rather want to do `list.addAll(retBetween(++index, lowerValue, upperValue))` instead of the previous mentioned `return`

Comment: how would that look structurally?

Comment: `if (index < elements.size()){ //line that prevents overflow.` I don't see a List with name element defined anywhere. Is element a global variable. If so can you add it to the code.

Comment: @ArthurDecker just added it

Answer (score 1):

You´re having two problems, one you´re not getting to as of now.

```
private RecursiveMethodsList<E> returnBetween(int index, T lowerValue, T upperValue){ 

   RecursiveMethodsList<T> list = new RecursiveMethodsList<T>(); 

   if (index < elements.size()){ //line that prevents overflow 

      if (elements.get(index).compareTo(lowerValue) >= 0 &&
         (elements.get(index).compareTo(upperValue)) <= 0){

         list.add(elements.get(index));
      }
      // Heres your mistake
      // You essentially pass index all the time, as index++ 
      // Will simply pass index instead of what you think index +1 , and increment index afterwards.
      // You probably also want to add the content of the List generated in
      // the recursive call to the original List you´re using here
      else list.addAll(retBetween(++index, lowerValue, upperValue)); 

   }
   return list; 
}
```

Comment: but if it doesn't meet the condition to add then it just calls the method again with an increased index...that's what I had originally how is it different from what you've written?

Comment: @emmynaki that´s your problem, imagine `index=1`, the recursive call wouldn´t pass `2` as `index`, it would pass `1` and increase the local `index` variable by `1` making it `2` afterwards. Essentially the recursive call will pass `0` all the time, if the first iteration didn´t find a result. For the second one, you´re never touching the `List` from the first call, so if the first call here wouldn´t find something and would go into recursion your returned `List` would have been empty every time, where you didn´t get to due to the exception.

Comment: do you know why my .add doesn't actually add anything? @SomeJavaGuy

Comment: @emmynaki it does, but only for the local instance of `RecursiveMethodsList`, which will be a different one with each recursion. the initial caller list starting the recursion would have been allways empty here if you wont handle the list instances from the recursive calls.

Comment: so I could fix it? If I make the list a parameter or using this that doesn't do much... @SomeJavaGuy

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
else retBetween(index++, lowerValue, upperValue);
```

you're post-incrementing the index because of which the next recursive call receives the same index value instead of incremented value, hence the stack overflow error.

Either put `index++` before calling the recursive method or do pre-increment like `retBetween(++index, lowerValue, upperValue)`

Comment: do you know why my method doesn't actually add anything to my list?

Comment: remove **else** from the line `else list.addAll(retBetween(++index, lowerValue, upperValue));`

Comment: your list gets replaced every time for each recursive iteration, when the condition(i.e., `index < elements.size()`)  becomes false then the value of the list will be empty in that iteration which will be returned as the result, that's why you need to do list.addAll(<recursion-method>) so the list contents of every iteration will be added to first iteration's list (which is what you return as the result as per the recursion concept)